# webpack-dev-server does not watch on the new files created

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I would like webpack to detect new changes for freshly created files.

My complete `webpack.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/js/index.js',

  output: {
    path: 'public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : [],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']}
    ]
  },

}
```

I have googled and searched but can't find anything that will automatically add new files to my watcher.

Comment: Are you using webpack 1 or webpack 2?

Comment: sorry, yes at the time of writing 2 wasn't a thing :) `1.13.1`

Answer (score 4):

There's couple of ways really.

1. if you are using cli, then you can write `$ webpack-dev-server --content-base src/`. More from [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base).
2. if you want the code to be included in you webconfig,

   ```
   devServer: {
       contentBase: "./src",
   }
   ```

   More from [weback](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver).

Here `contentBase` is the directory where you want `webpack-dev-server` to listen and read the files from.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Humm this works for .js files but not for my scss files, I am testing more

Answer (score 2):

you should run the server with this command:

`webpack-dev-server --progress --hot`